# Compile and run test with junit-4.12.jar and hamcrest-core-1.3.jar on command line? Error: is abstract, can not be instantiated, can not find symbol

Tags: java, junit4

I am trying to do java unit testing and this is what i have done so far:

in file Test.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{
    public String getString(int n){
        return String.valueOf(n);
    }

    public int max(int a, int b){
        if(a>b) return a;
        return b;
    }

    public int maxOf(int []a){
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            if (a[i]>max) max=a[i];
        }

        return max;
    }

    public String BMI(int weight, int height){
        double BMI = weight/(height*height);
        if(BMI < 18.5) return "Insufficient";
        else if (BMI>=18.5 && BMI<=22.99) return "Normal";
        else if (BMI>=23 && BMI<=24.99) return "Overweight";
        return "Fat";
    }
}
```

And then i wrote another file called Testtest.java in the same directory:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Testtest{
    @Test
    void testString(){
        Test case1 = new Test();
        String result = case1.getString(1);
        // System.out.println(result);
        assertEquals("1", result);
    }
    @Test
    public void testMax(){
        Test newTest = new Test();
        int max = newTest.max(2, 4);
        assertEquals(4, max);
    }

    @Test 
    public void testMaxOf(){
        Test newTest = new Test();
        int[] anArray = { 
            10,4,55,66,8,2,33,102
        };
        int max = newTest.maxOf(anArray);
        assertEquals(102, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBMI(){
        Test newTest = new Test();
        String result = newTest.BMI(60, 1.65);
        assertEquals("Normal", result);
    }
}
```

This directory now has the following files:

```
junit-4.12.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
Test.java
Testtest.java
```

Then i cd into the directory in the command line:
First i compiled the Test.java with javac as usual, then i compiled the Testtest.java with this:

> javac -cp junit-4.12.jar;. Testtest.java

and it show me this
[Error as mentioned in the title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efbNj.png)

i have tried it many time, i know it would be easier if i use IDE but for a number of reasons, i really want to do it using just text editor and command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are testing, Test, I would consider naming something else.  That class is most certainly not abstract, so my guess is that Java is trying to do something else with a call to Test than create an object of the class you made.  Keep in mind, class names also typically start with a lowercase letter, and have to mirror the name of the .java file.

Other than that, it should work.  Although, just to note, in testBMI(), you are passing an int and a double to a method that accepts two ints only.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, i have been so frustrated trying to figure this out when all i have to do was changing the name of the class. Also, tks for remind me of the tesBMI().